How to draw graphs with various-looking edges in Unity?
I'm making a game in Unity, and I have some set of "nodes" and relationships between them. I've been looking for a way to visualize these relationships (i.e. draw a graph).
But all the solutions I've found have been either crude, using GameObjects, or poorly configurable, using meshes or Unity.GL. LineRenderer is also a bad fit, since it's impossible to make the rendered line look different in different areas, if needed. I could use multiple LineRenderers, but I think it's too inconvenient. But I've seen examples that it's possible. Cell to Singularity Beyond research tree looks kinda insane, and it's made on Unity. Any ideas how that's possible?

I could use multiple LineRenderers, but I think it's too inconvenient. .. why? And what is the issue with using GL?

Made with 2D Canvas and horizontal layout, where we have a basic visual preset block of pictures. Lines - this can be a linerender, because your linerender essentially creates a mesh grid, and you can use any material. Understanding a little ShaderGraph, you can easily repeat any effect from your example.
